# Injecting a service via a InvocationHandler

Tags: java, spring

Is there a clean way in Spring (with no XML) to have an interface wired to an invocation handler? Currently I have to do something like this:

```
@Inject
private ServiceProxyCreator services;

private MyServiceInterface service;

private MyServiceInterface getService() {
   if ( service == null )
      service = services.createProxy( MyServiceInterface.class );

   return service;
}
```

Where #createProxy is simply an implementation of something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
public <T> T createProxy( Class<T> type ) {
    JobRpcHandler handler = new JobRpcHandler();
    handler.setServiceName( type.getSimpleName() );
    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        type.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{type}, handler );
}
```

But with all this DI functionality in Spring it seems like I should be able to do this all automatically so that I can simply do the following:

```
@Inject
private MyService service;
```

With the injection customized in some way that I don't know to create the Proxy behind the scenes without having to call #createProxy.

Any suggestions on a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [FactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-factorybean). You can write your own this way:

```
public class ServiceProxyFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Object>
    private Class<T> type;

    public DutySetFactoryBean(Class<?> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Object getObject() {
        JobRpcHandler handler = new JobRpcHandler();
        handler.setServiceName(type.getSimpleName());
        return Proxy.newProxyInstance(type.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{type}, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and use it in your configuration file:

```
<bean class="package.name.ServiceProxyFactoryBean">
  <constructor-arg>
    <value type="java.lang.Class">package.name.MyServiceInterface</value>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

or, using Java configuration, that way:

```
@Bean
public ServiceProxyFactoryBean myServiceFactoryBean() {
    return new ServiceProxyFactoryBean(MyServiceInterface.class);
}

@Bean
public MyServiceInterface myService() {
  return (MyServiceInterface)sessionFactoryBean().getObject();
}
```

---

If you want automatically create proxies for all the annotated interfaces in a classpath, you can define your own [BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html). Here you must scan your classpath with [ResourceLoader](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) using the following pattern:

```
MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory = new SimpleMetadataReaderFactory();
Resource[] resources = patternResolver.getResources(
        "classpath*:" + packageName.replace('.', '/') + "/**/*.class");
for (Resource resource : resources) {
    MetadataReader reader = metadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(resource);
    if (!reader.getAnnotationMetadata().isAnnotated(
            MyProxyAnnotation.class.getName())) {
        continue;
    }
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(reader.getClassMetadata().getClassName(), true,
            resourceLoader.getClassLoader());
    String factoryBeanName = createNewName();
    BeanDefinitionBuilder bdb = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(
            ServiceProxyFactoryBean.class);
    bdb.addConstructorArgValue(cls);
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(factoryBeanName, bdb.getBeanDefinition());
    bdb = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(cls);
    bdb.setFactoryBean(factoryBeanName, "getBean");
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(createNewName(), bdb.getBeanDefinition());
}
```

Now, for all interfaces, annotated with `MyProxyAnnotation`, you have a proxy, which you can inject into your beans. For example:

```
@MyProxyAnnotation
public interface MyServiceInterface {
    void foo();
}
```

And

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    @Autowired
    private MyServiceInterface myService;
}
```

That's all. No configuration needed.

I am not sure this code works or even compiles. It not the final solution, just a general way you should move toward. So you should research and debug a little.

Comment: I'm not even sure why I'd want to use FactoryBean. I mean, if I have to create a Bean method on one of my configuration classes for each class then can't I just create the proxy in the myService Bean method? What do I get with the factory? I was hoping there was a way to do this without having to make a bean method for EVERY remote interface. But I also could not be fully understanding your example.

Comment: @user1888440, if I understood you, you don't want to register these beans manually? Much like it done with stereotypes (@Component and others). So, you can slighly extend Spring to do it for you. I edited my answer and added there description of how you should do.